# Where does ray[tune] record `python-core-worker-*.log` files?

Tags: ray

Maybe a dumb question since I'm new to `ray`, but my (single machine) hyperparameter tuning test run is getting some `ERROR`ed trials, and I'm seeing the following messages suggesting I need to find worker logs in order to see a stack trace from my experiment code:

```
2021-03-14 22:16:56,198 WARNING worker.py:1107 -- A worker died or was killed while executing task ffffffffffffffff06c82ce3c4361bef34d813e601000000.
2021-03-14 22:16:56,201 ERROR trial_runner.py:616 -- Trial experiment_fn_82158_00001: Error processing event.
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ray.exceptions.RayActorError: The actor died unexpectedly before finishing this task. Check python-core-worker-*.log files for more information.
```

Anyone know where to find those log files?

I checked the experiment directory under `local_dir`, but the only relevant file there is an `error.txt` with the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the optimization in linux, it is under

`tmp/ray/<your session>/logs`

Comment: those files have no data in them? is that correct?